# Flash transparent JPEG through Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash, transparency, jpeg

In Flash, via the authoring environment, you can put bitmaps in your movie that are compressed with JPEG but still support full alpha transparency, something JPEG does not support out-of-the-box. Is there a way to achieve the same when embedding bitmaps via the Flex `[Embed]` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not something that is possible using Embed.  A workaround I have used is to embed both the JPEG and a transparency mask and apply the mask programmatically.  If possible, I recommend using transparent PNGs instead.

Comment: Transparent PNGs are better, but unfortunately too large for my purposes.